# PHLivePhotoView static picture looks pixelated

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch, phlivephoto

I'm using `requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs` to set a `PHLivePhotoView`'s `livePhoto` property. One of the parameters when calling `requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs` is the `targetSize` which is a `CGSize`. First I tried simply passing in the `PHLivePhotoView`'s frame's size as the argument, this resulted in a very blurry picture. Then I tried passing in `CGSizeZero`, this resulted in a very pixelated image. It would appear as if the `CGSizeZero` argument resulted in the image being too high resolution for the display (running on iPhone 6S) and this led to a kind of pixelated effect. Also, not sure if this is related, but I'm getting the following printout from the terminal when I call `requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs`.

*** error reading settings archive file: ISRootSettings: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F4100B0E-B498-444A-AD6D-7E2CEDB25095/Documents/({my bundle identifier}).settings/ISRootSettings_10.plist

I've tried changing the photos, changing where in my bundle the photos are placed, and the extensions. This message always prints out. I have tried googling it plenty of times and can't ever seem to find anything.

My question is, what `CGSize` should I be passing in to get a proper image?

Comment: have the same issue, have you found a solution ?

Comment: Same issue, any clues?